# PostScript copy operator for arrays

Tags: arrays, postscript

I'm looking for some extra detailed information on the *copy operator* in PostScript when using it with arrays (or dictionaries/strings/...).

In the PostScript Language Reference Manual I find:

*array1  array2 **copy**  subarray2*

On a website I've found this example: http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/July1999/article100.html

```
GS>[1 2 3] [4 5 6 7 8] copy pstack
[1 2 3]
GS<1>/ar [4 5 6 7 8] def
GS<1>[1 2 3] ar copy
GS<2>ar pstack
[1 2 3 7 8]
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
GS<3>
```

But this example confuses me because of [1 2 3] and [1 2 3 7 8].

Now how exactly does the copy operator work with arrays? 
If I have this stack:

```
---------------top-
copy
[4 5 6 7 8]
[1 2 3]
------------bottom-
```

**After the copy operation** what stays on the stack?

Only the subarray?:

```
---------------top-
[1 2 3]
------------bottom-
```

or subarray + part of array 2?:

```
---------------top-
[1 2 3 7 8]
------------bottom-
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PostScript Language Reference Manual, 3rd edition, page 548, the copy operator:

> '...In the other forms, copy copies all the elements of the first
>   composite object into the second. The composite object operands must
>   be of the same type, except that a packed array can be copied into an
>   array (and only into an array—copy cannot copy into packed arrays,
>   because they are read-only). This form of copy copies the value of a
>   composite object. This is quite different from dup and other operators
>   that copy only the objects themselves (see Section 3.3.1, “Simple and
>   Composite Objects”). However, copy performs only one level of copying.
>   It does not apply recursively to elements that are themselves
>   composite objects; instead, the values of those elements become
>   shared.
>
> In the case of arrays or strings, the length of the second object must
>   be at least as great as the first; copy returns the initial subarray
>   or substring of the second operand into which the elements were
>   copied. Any remaining elements of array2 or string2 are unaffected.'

In your case you are (I think) being tripped up by the fact that compound objects are referenced. You need to think of composite objects on the stack in terms of pointers, or references, rather than physical chunks of memory.

So in the first instance, you create 2 arrays and place pointers to them on the stack, neither of these has any other references pointing to them. You then execute copy.

The copy operator copies the first 3 elements from the array pointed to by the first operand into the array pointed to by the second operand. It then creates a new sub-array which contains only the modified elements.

It then removes the 2 arrays from the stack, if you think of these as pointers it simply removes the pointers from the stack. Since these arrays are not referenced anywhere else, the memory is then freed.

Finally it puts a pointer to the new array on the stack. pstack resolves the pointer to the array and prints the resulting elements.

Now, in the second case you create an array and reference it from the name /ar (which will be stored in the current dictionary). You then create a second array and put a reference (pointer) to it on the operand stack, then you put a reference to 'ar' on the stack.

Next you call copy. Copy copies the first 3 elements from the initial array to the array referenced by 'ar'. It also creates a new sub-array. Then it removes the references to the operands from the operand stack. Since the initial array is now unreferenced it is freed. However, the current dictionary contains a key '/ar' whose value is a reference to the second array. So we don't free the memory associated with it, it is still referenced. Finally it puts the new subarray on the stack

You then put another reference to the array keyed by '/ar' on the stack and again call pstack. pstack resolves the array references and prints the contents.

As you see, copy altered the first 3 elements of the array referenced by '/ar' and also returned a subarray containing the copied elements.

NB In the original example, the first 'copy' leaves a reference to an array containing [1 2 3] on the stack (printed by the first pstack). This is why the second pstack (after the second execution of copy) prints what is apparently the same array twice, it isn't, it printing referecnes to two different subarrays, each one returned by one of the executions of 'copy'. So instead of :

we could have simply done:

```
GS>[1 2 3] [4 5 6 7 8] copy pstack
[1 2 3]
GS<1>/ar [4 5 6 7 8] def
GS<1> ar copy
GS>ar pstack
[1 2 3 7 8]
[1 2 3]
GS<2>
```

That is we take the [1 2 3] subarray resulting from the first copy, and use it as the initial operand to the second copy.

Notice that the 'GS' prompt has digits indicating the number of entries on the operand stack.

So, to answer your original question, **nothing** stays on the stack, both operands are removed, and a new subarray is created, and a reference to it placed on the stack.

Comment: actually "[1 2 3] [4 5 6 7 8] copy" is a useless operation, you could maybe better pop the array so that you have [1 2 3] on the stack.
If I understand correctly, copy becomes useful if you have array references (/ar ... def).